Sequential numbering for figures and tables across different chapters
I have a Quarto book rendered to PDF and I am trying to change the figure numbering so that it is sequential rather than starting at each chapter. For example, I do not want my figures to be labelled 'Figure 1.1', 'Figure 2.1', 'Figure 2.2', but 'Figure 1' 'Figure 2', and 'Figure 3'. The same should apply to tables.
My editor is very insistent on this and technically wants me to label tables as figures - do you know of any way to achieve this?

Could you provide a minimal example so we can better understand your setup?

Following this TeX.se answer, it should be sufficient to place \counterwithout{figure}{chapter} in the header-includes metadata field.:
header-includes:
  - '`\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}`{=latex}'

Or use the method described in LaTeX includes to supply the \counterwithout{figure}{chapter} snippet.

This worked! Thank you so much.
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
